# Configuring Graphql Resolver with Azure Function and HttpTrigger by POST

Tags: graphql, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I have an API Management Service in Azure, there I'm trying to configure my first mutation but I'm having troubles configuring the Resolver Policiy, let me share more details:

Here is my mutation:

[image]

my ResolverPolicy looks like this:

```
<http-data-source>
    <http-request>
      <set-method>POST</set-method>
      <set-url>[URL]</set-url>
      <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
        <value>application/json</value>
      </set-header>
      <set-body>@{
        var args = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(true)["arguments"];  
        JObject jsonObject = new JObject();
        jsonObject.Add("messageId", args["messageId"]);
        jsonObject.Add("senderUserId", args["senderUserId"]);
        jsonObject.Add("receiverUserId", args["receiverUserId"]);
        jsonObject.Add("messageContent", args["messageContent"]);
        return jsonObject.ToString();
      }</set-body>
    </http-request>
  </http-data-source>
```

when I try to run this, Azure says

[image]

Here is my full schema:

```
schema {
  query: ChatMessageQueries
  mutation: ChatMessageMutations
}

scalar UUID @specifiedBy(url: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122")

 type ChatMessageMutations {
  SendChatTextMessage(input: SendChatTextMessageInput!): SendChatMessageResp
}

input SendChatTextMessageInput {
  messageId: UUID!
  senderUserId: UUID!
  receiverUserId: UUID!
  messageContent: String!
}

enum ChatMessageSendStatus {
  SUCCESS
  FAIL
}

 type ChatMessageErrorData {
  code: Int
  message: String
}

 type SendChatMessageResp {
  messageId: UUID!
  status: ChatMessageSendStatus!
  error: ChatMessageErrorData
}

 type ChatTextMessage {
  messageId: UUID!
  senderUserId: UUID!
  receiverUserId: UUID!
  messageContent: String!
}

 type ChatMessageQueries {
  GetUserChatMessages(userId: UUID!): [ChatTextMessage]
}
```

I configured my mutation by GET and it worked fine, but we need to run it by POST

What's is wrong with my Resolver Policy?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please share your complete schema

Comment: HI @IkhtesamAfrin, I edited my question and there I added my full schema. Any comment please? Regards

Comment: At what point you have added the Resolver?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74177864/azure-apim-synthetic-graphql-mutation-resolver, I believe this issue is not yet fixed.

Comment: Yes, I had checked before asking my question, cause I tried that and it doesn't work. 

The resolved is added in the config, see that in the Resolver Policy xml theres is a tag which is <set-url> which has my azure function URL.

Answer (score 0):

As per the investigation we identified below two issues.

1.HTTP resolver with set-body - Request set-body policy not invoked in http-data-source. It does affect the same scenario that the older issue was describing [in this pos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74177864/azure-apim-synthetic-graphql-mutation-resolver), so it is a regression. That is, the old issue was fixed, however the functionality there regressed in a different manner, due to another bug.

2.Resolver testing UI - Fails with Internal Server Error when using generic notation (eg. As()) in set-body

Our product team is working on the fix, No ETA available as of now. Would recommend you track update in https://github.com/Azure/API-Management/releases.

We apologize for the inconvenience caused by the issue. Feel free to add a comment if any questions.